# Error while compiling Android Volley code

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i have this error while compiling this piece of code:

```
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    testtext.setText(response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    testtext.setText(error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    queue.add(getRequest);
```

The code is supposed to send get request from an url, and get JSON from it. But i'm getting an error while compiling it:

```
Error:(65, 86) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try adding `null` as the third parameter to the `JsonObjectRequest` constructor.

Comment: I tried, but it everything turned into underlined red, as some kind of error.

Comment: Can you localize the exact place of the error with the given `Error(65, 86)` ?

Comment: Error is in this line of code: `JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,` At very end

Comment: It looks to me like an issue with the signature of the constructor you're attempting to use. `JsonObjectRequest` has two constructors itself, with signatures `int, String, JSONObject, Listener<JSONObject>, ErrorListener` and `String, JSONObject, Listener<JSONObject>, ErrorListener`. Neither of those match the signature of the constructor being used, which is `int, String, Listener<JSONObject>, ErrorListener`. That's why I recommended trying to add `null` as the third parameter, so you'd be using the 5 parameter constructor.

Comment: Ok, I tried setting the 3rd parameter to null, it compiled, somehow. But when i ran it on my phone, the app crashed.

Comment: What was the exception stack trace you received when it crashed?